# Shiny fileInput - just the button, no text or loading bar

Tags: html, r, file, shiny

I want to allow users to upload certain files and update the dashboard in accordance to new data. I'm creating a custom modal with instruction, and I need a button that will open the file explorer and allow the user to upload a file.
The best functionality I've found is `fileInput()` from Shiny. However, it also includes a textbox listing the file location and a progress bar for the upload. These parts are unnecessary for my purposes.

Is there a way to get just the button and its functionality? I actually managed to do this myself with htmltools:

```
library(htmltools)
library(shiny)

fileInput_button <- fileInput("user_sent_data",
                              "Choose file...", 
                              accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx"))

fileInput_button <- htmltools::tagQuery(fileInput_button)$
  find(".input-group-btn.input-group-prepend")$
  selectedTags()

# We need to replace the text in the span, so we'll extract the unchanging part,
# empty the original (text + extracted part) and the fill it back with the extracted part
fileInput_text <- "Choose file..."

input_part <- htmltools::tagQuery(fileInput_button)$find("input")$
  selectedTags()

fileInput_button <- htmltools::tagQuery(fileInput_button)$
  find("span")$
  empty()$ # getting rid of the text and input_part
  append(fileInput_text, input_part)$
  allTags()
```

...and then I include `fileInput_button` in my UI definition.
My question is, is there a better approach to achieve the same solution and functionality?
Other packages with such functionality are appreciated too. I think using a plain HTML  wouldn't work because I can't find a way to open the file browser that also allows me to specify one can only select .csv and .xlsx files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `accept` attribute to specify which file extensions are allowed:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  tags$input(
    id = "upload", 
    type = "file", 
    accept = ".csv", 
    style = "color: transparent;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$upload, {
    print(input$upload)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By default, the text "No file chosen" appears next to the button. In the above app, this text is hidden thanks to the CSS `style = "color: transparent;"`.

The button is not very stylish. An alternative allowing to use a Shiny action button consists in hiding the file input with some CSS and to trigger the click on this file input when the user clicks on the action button:

```r
css <- "
#upload {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  br(),
  tags$input(
    id = "upload", 
    type = "file", 
    accept = ".csv"
  ),
  actionButton("btn", "Choose file", onclick = "$('#upload').click();")
)
```

Comment: Creative solution, I like it! Thank you.
The second solution you wrote might be more practical in a larger app than my initial one.