# RShiny set fileInput() button back to default style

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an RShiny web application and use the fileInput() functionality:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
 tabPanel("Inputs",
             sidebarPanel(textInput("name", "Name:", ""),  
                          fileInput("file", "Upload file (.xlsx)", accept = c(".xlsx")))
```

I like the button that comes as a default with fileInput:

[image]

However some piece of css in my code is overwriting the default option and turning the button into this:

[image]

I can't figure out what exactly is overwriting the default option in my code. And I also saw that using a button from the bootstrap utility class is not an option for fileInput(). What can I do to bring back the default button?

Comment: Can you provide any sort of reproducible example? It's very hard to help without any sort of code to look at. Have you used your browser's devtools to see which CSS rules are being applied?

Comment: This is the normal rendering, it is not due to your css.

Comment: See <https://stackoverflow.com/a/77901988/1100107>.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you for your answer, I am not sure if I understand what you mean. What steps should I take to have the default button of fileInput() instead of wht I have now?

Comment: @Afke The picture you show *is* the default.

Comment: @McFlick thanks for your answer, unfortunately I can't share a reproducible example as I do not know how to reproduce this at the moment. Because I don't know what is causing the fact that I do not see the default button displayed..

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that is true, but that is not what is showing in my web application (I took it from the internet ;)), what is showing in my web app is the blue "Browse..." button instead. But I want this button to look like the default.. It did before but then I uploaded some .css files and it was gone..

Comment: @Afke I mean the Browse button *is* the default in Shiny. If you want the native HTML button, see the link I posted.